# Python threading on multiple CPU Cores

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Using the following program i get almost 100% CPU usage of all cores. I'm using a Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8 on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit system and python 3.8. I always thought python is using green threads and can only use one core at a time because of the GIL. At https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock is written:

"The mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one thread executes Python bytecode at a time. This simplifies the CPython implementation by making the object model (including critical built-in types such as dict) implicitly safe against concurrent access. Locking the entire interpreter makes it easier for the interpreter to be multi-threaded, at the expense of much of the parallelism afforded by multi-processor machines."

what am I wrong with the whole thing?

```
from threading import Thread

class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1000000):
            print(f"Thread {self.name} is running")


def create_threads():
    for i in range(100000):
        name = f"#{i}"
        my_thread = TestThread(name)
        my_thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
The CPU load proably comes from the kernel performing all the IO I guess. But what I still don't understand is why it makes such a big difference, if i'm only using one python thread that performs a lot of IO.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_threads()
    for i in range(100000000):
        print(f"in loop {i}")
```

[image]

Comment: Where do your millions and millions of lines of output go? It makes more sense to test this with code that actually computes something (for a minimum of several seconds per iteration), instead of using I/O so heavily.

Comment: I found this test on a youtube video and wanted to test if it's fake. So all the CPUs are used by the OS to perform the IO?

Comment: There might be some problems here. 1. The graph is not accurate enough to show you the extremely fast thread changes. 2. There are probably many background processes that add some load to your CPU. Those are just 2 examples of why you can't see the effects of the GIL this way.

Comment: For what it's worth: I've run your program on my machine (AMD 3600x, with 6 cores/12 threads available, running Ubuntu 21.04). When I let all the output be printed to the terminal, I see my load average going above 2 (thus 2 threads on average), measured with `htop` for ease and live monitoring. When I sent the output of the script to `/dev/null`, the load average drops towards 1. Which indicates the extra load/thread was because of writing to the terminal.

Comment: So I guess this is the same for you: other processes take up extra cores/threads. You should create a graph where the first 10-20 seconds, your system is idle, before you start the program.